# Android 11 : Camera Intent Crashes on Orientation Change After Image Capture

Tags: android, camera, android-11

I am capturing an image (Portrait + Landscape) using camera intent and showing it in an image view in Fragment.

I had followed all instructions from the below link,

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

The Code is working fine on devices till Android 10, but not working on Android 11 devices **(especially Samsung Phones)**.

I had tried all possible solutions on Stack Overflow.

The application crashes in the below scenario only,

Steps to reproduce,

1. User Launches Camera to capture the image
2. Rotates the Phone to capture the image in landscape mode.
3. User Captures the image successfully and clicks on the tick or OK.
   *If the Image captured in Portrait mode, then the application doesn't crash.*

I am getting the below error, (reported on Crashlytics)

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:283)
       at com.kyc.views.PDFragment.onActivityResult(PDFragment.java:442)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.kyc/com.kyc.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65660, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.kyc/com.kyc.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4852)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4885)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
```

Comment: In onActivityResult() you use a variable which you asigned a value before you started the Camera. But while using the camera your app was in the background and got killed -maybe by the rotation- you should not assume that that variable still holds that value when onCreate() is called again. Check for null before use. Use onSaveInstanceState() to save those values.

Comment: @blackapps: Thanks for the suggestion but my question is why it is happening only on Android 11?

Comment: Same problem getting for me. Any Solution find

Comment: same problem.. any solution found?

Comment: same problem for me...any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Handle "config changes" by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity in Manifest. Problem is rotation after you back to your app when screen is rotating back to portrait. Some phones can handle this, some not.

Answer (score 0):

For new android versions, we should use **screenSize** along with orientation

like below

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```