# Android Image FIle variable is becoming null after image capture

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-file, android-fileprovider

The app I am currently developing has the feature of being able to capture an image, record a video, browse and upload a media file from gallery. Problem is, the app works well enough in emulator. Without any errors (checked with android 9+ emulators). But the app behaves unexpectedly while testing on physical device (Android 10). Unexpected, because, video recording and playing works fine, as well as browsing and uploading media from gallery. What fails is image capture. The thing is the image file is actually getting created, But I am getting the image file variable `photoFile` value as `null` in `onActivityResult()` method.

Here is the implementation:

`manifest.xml`

```
    <provider android:name=".utils.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.app.mtccrm.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

`provider_paths.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

`method to create image_file`

```
    public static File createImageFile(Context mContext, String name) throws IOException {
        
        String imageFileName = name.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = new File(storageDir + File.separator + imageFileName + ".png");
        return image;
    }
```

`method responsible for opening the camera`

```
    private void openCamera() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddNewFileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE_IMAGE);
        } else {
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            try {
                photoFile = CommonMethod.createImageFile(this, fileName);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, ""+photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(photoFile != null ) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_CODE);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong while trying to create a file. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

`onActivityResult()`

```
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+photoFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(photoFile == null) {
                if(data != null) {
                   parseGalleryFile(data);
                }
            }else {
                setImage(Uri.parse(photoFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
```

The first Toast in onActivityResult() gives me `null` value. So somehow the `photoFile` variable is becoming null, however I am at a loss about the cause. Since, from the same activity using the same methods, recording of videos and browsing gallery works just fine. I thought it might have something to do with the activity getting paused when the camera is called. So, I added this

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState, @NonNull PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+photoFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(photoFile != null) {
            outState.putString("FileId", photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+savedInstanceState.getString("FileId"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(savedInstanceState.getString("FileId") != null) {
            if (photoFile == null) {
                photoFile = new File(savedInstanceState.getString("FileId"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, save and restore state methods are not getting called, so that means the activity is not being paused. So what could be the cause for `photofile` becoming null? what exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Android lesson one: your activity can be killed at any moment. Especially if other activities or apps are on top of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548466/android-11-camera-intent-crashes-on-orientation-change-after-image-capture?noredirect=1#comment117722948_66548466

Comment: if you look carefully I have both ``saveInstanceState()`` and ``restoreInstanceState()`` methods defined.

Comment: Sorry i did not look at your code as i directly assumed you did not save. Well if it is null at restore then you did something wrong.

Comment: `The thing is the image file is actually getting created,` Ok. And file size > 0? Use log statements in in the save and restore functions instead of toasts. Please report. Further all looks ok at first sight.

Comment: Yes, I am able to open the file using my phone's file manage. The state methods, seem to be not getting called, since there is neither log output not toast, making me believe the activity is not getting paused. Hence I am at a loss as to why the value comes as a null. And that too for taking picture. As I said, Recording of video, or browsing gallery works like a charm. I also have ``requestLegacyExternalStorage`` set to true in manifest.

Comment: I dont know too. Check if you declared variable photoFile twice. Maybe somewhere local too.

Comment: `I am able to open the file using my phone's file manage` Then your device does not run Android 11.

Comment: Try other devices.

Comment: The problem is, it's inconsistency. I have checked with 4 emulators having android 8 to 11. there were no errors. as for physical devices, don't have many, I have one running android 10 where the app crashed for photo capture. The other one running android 9, works just fine. Since the QA team is testing this issue in android 10, I am unable to close it.

Comment: Is there any other approach by which I can achieve image capture, maybe specifically for android 10?

Comment: There is no reason your -standard- code would not be usable for Android 10. Blame the manufacturer. Try other Android 10 devices. Which phone is it?

Comment: `I have one running android 10 where the app crashed for photo capture. ` For what reason? For that variable being null? Check for null before use and dont use if null.

Comment: Samsung M1 and Redmi 7a are the phones that I have tested on. Yeah, I have to display the captured image, but since the variable is null there is nothing displayed. So either I leave it as non-displayed or, I let the app crash. In both cases this is a issue. What I am more confused about is why video record is working, whereas this isn't. I tried changing the create file method to the one used for creating video-file, but then again the issue persists.